# How to get Youtube video information with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, youtube

I'm trying to figure out how to get all the information of a Youtube video with jquery and am having only a little success.

I used the following code to get the video title and description...

```
var url = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=" + id + "&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc";
var title;

$.getJSON(url,
    function(response)
    {
        title = response.data.items[0].title;
        description = response.data.items[0].description;
        author = response.data.items[0].name;

        $('#details-title').text("Title: " + title);
        $('#details-desc').text("Description: " + description);
    }
);
```

How would I figure out what other fields can be received with this method? For instance, I'm trying to get the uploader name, and video length.

Comment: `console.log(response)` and inspect what data is available, or go to the api documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the `id` in your url with a valid query and access that url, it will return a JSON object.

Now copy that JSON object and put it inside a beautifier (in my case I use [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/)) and check the children of `items` and choose what other fields you need.